# want semaphore to exceed SEM_VALUE_MAX

Tags: c, posix, max, semaphore

I'm working on a program with critical sections, so I am using semaphores. Specifically, the POSIX semaphores: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sem_close.3.html

According to http://www.sbin.org/doc/glibc/libc_34.html (search: macro SEM_VALUE_MAX ), there is a maximum value that the general semaphore can be set to. On my system, this is about 32K.

Unfortunately, I'm dealing with some time-sensitive code (reading form an arduino via a serial port at ~1MBit/s), so I'd like to have larger semaphores, because of some implementation details. Ideally, I'd like them to be able to be at least 2^20, but I'm a little unclear on why there is an upper limit anyway.

Is there any way to exceed this SEM_VALUE_MAX, and get a semaphore with a larger value? I could only think of:

1. Redefining SEM_VALUE_MAX

   - probably a horrible idea; I think those POSIX folks know what they're doing
2. Having a semaphore refer to more than one 'chunk' of data

   - right now, each up() or down() only acquires/releases a single 'chunk' -- an unsigned short int.
   - I imagine dealing with multiple at a time could cause deadlock.
3. Implementing my own semaphores.

   - time consuming / redundant work
   - less portable
4. Ask you wonderful folks what you think!

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just use the semaphore to protect access to another counter that you use to track the allocations.  That way you don't need any more semaphore values than you have accessors.

Comment: that's a good point! I'm trying to use the semaphores for condition synchronization. Is protecting a counter via a binary semaphore a common way of implementing condition sync? I think I know how to implement your way, but I want to follow best practices / make things portable (hence, I was trying to keep everything encapsulated in just the semaphore)

Comment: IMO - typically I use a semaphore to protect some data structure not as a counter in itself.   The structure can be as simple as a counter.  I'm sure others do use them as counters, just not something I've done.

Comment: _Is protecting a counter via a binary semaphore a common way of implementing condition sync?_ Yes, yes it is (If your synchronization is with a counter)

Comment: The whole point of a semaphore is to be a counter in itself. If you're going to use it to protect another variable, then you lose the whole signaling power of semaphores, and to get it back you'd have to switch to using mutexes and cond vars.

Answer (score 1):

How portable do you need your program to be? `_POSIX_SEM_VALUE_MAX` is the **minimum** value of `SEM_VALUE_MAX` that is POSIX-conforming. Larger values are always allowed. glibc and other real-world implementations I'm familiar with have `SEM_VALUE_MAX` defined much larger, usually equal to `INT_MAX`. The only way you need to worry about this is if you want your program to be portable to other POSIX systems that have a very low `SEM_VALUE_MAX`.